# How to create an "=" operator to check if a Structure type is null

Tags: vb.net, operators

I have never had any issues creating an operator before, but this time I am stumped. My goal is to be able to use the `=` operator to check if my structure type is null. Example: `If myStruct = Nothing Then`. I have tried several different failed approaches and haven't been successful in finding any documentation for my issue. I am not sure how to set an object identifier type to be a null identifier:

***Operator within the `PhoneNumber` structure:***

```
Public Shared Operator =(number As PhoneNumber, null As Nothing) As Boolean ' <== Error for type "Nothing": Keyword does not name a type.
    Return IsDBNull(number)
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>(number As PhoneNumber, null As Nothing) As Boolean ' <== Error for type "Nothing": Keyword does not name a type.
    Return Not IsDBNull(number)
End Operator
```

***Checking if the structure is null:***

```
Friend Sub Foo(num as PhoneNumber)
   If myStruct = Nothing Then
      ' Do something
   Else
      ' Do something else
   End If
End Sub
```

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do? If so, could you all point me in the direction to figure this out? I would prefer to understand how all this works, but I'll be happy to accept a solution/answer as an alternative.

Comment: If myStruct is Nothing Then

Comment: I thought so too, but when I tried that I was getting the error: "'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'PhoneNumber'. Operands must be reference or nullable types."

Comment: Sorry, missed that. If PhoneNumber is a Structure then it's a value type, not a reference type so can't be Null/Nothing.  Maybe add a boolean property for 'IsInitialised' with a default of False, and set it when 'created' (allocated a value) then test for IsInitialised rather than = Nothing

Comment: Also your Operator tests if PhoneNumber (a structure) is DBNull.  I don't believe a structure can be DBNull, although one or more of its properties could.  Maybe post the definition of your PhoneNumber structure and how you are using it for more help

Comment: @JonRoberts if it's truly a `Structure` then it can't be null.  `Nothing` will be equivalent to a default-initialized structure.

Comment: The way `DBNull` works, as I recall, is that you get an `Object` out of the accessor, and the object can either be a `DBNull` object or it can be the type you expect in the column.  (It has to be this way rather than `Nothing` because value types aren't nullable.)  There wouldn't be any such thing as your `PhoneNumber` being a `DBNull`.  Unfortunately, nullable value types didn't make it into .NET until 2.0 as I recall, so the 1.0 database design doesn't do nulls in the same way as one would expect in modern .NET.

Comment: Ok, well I have a public shared property called Empty, but I was really hoping not to have to use that as the solution. Based on what you're saying, there is no way around value types being equivalent to null?

Comment: Ah, well bummer. I was hoping there was a way around this, but I guess I'll just stick to using the `PhoneNumer.Empty` property for my empty/null checks. Thanks guys!

Comment: You do realise that nullable value types exist, right? Anywhere you would use `SomeValueType` you can use `Nullable(Of SomeValueType)` or `SomeValueType?` for short. You can then use the `HasValue` property to see whether the variable or whatever has a value and, if that's `True`, you can get the value from the `Value` property. You don't need any of what you're doing.

Comment: @Craig thanks. Must admit I thought vb.net Nothing = c# null, but I stand corrected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192049/nullin-c-vs-nothingin-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

with credit to @jmcilhinney's comment, this code works for me without error:

```
Private Structure TelephoneNo
  Public AreaCode As String
  Public telno As String
End Structure

Private Sub foo(num As Nullable(Of TelephoneNo))
  If num Is Nothing Then
     ' Do something
  Else
     ' Do something else
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can abbreviate `Nullable(Of TelephoneNo)` as `TelephoneNo?`.